# Magento Collection, how to obtain array of values of a particular field

Tags: magento

Starting from a Collection, I need to obtain an array of values of a particular field..let me call this field `my_id`.

To do this, I use the `Varien_Data_Collection::setDataToAll()` on my Collection..in this way:

```
$collection_fields_array = $collection->setDataToAll(array('my_id'))->toArray(array('my_id'));
```

..what I obtain is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 71e1bd18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 70d47a69
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 687bed84
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 673df159
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 66690a4c
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [my_id] => 65994440
        )
)
```

But..if my Collection contains a large number of items..`setDataToAll()` becomes too time consuming and finally crashes all 2Gb(!!!) of memory...this is because its iteration between all items.

Is another way to obtain an array of field values without this workaround?

Answer (score 40):

In this case,you can use ***`getColumnValues('fieldName')`***.

So,try this

`$collection->getColumnValues('my_id')`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been in your particular situation, but I've had similar problems when I wanted to perform an action on all orders in my site - the objects are large, and if I just did a collection of all orders, it would quickly fill the available memory and die.

In my case,  I was working with orders, so I started looping through and only selecting one month's worth at a time - a little extra code, but it made the collection size much more manageable. Could you do something similar here?

For example, if they're products, maybe filter on the product_id and do only 1,000 at a time, or for orders the date tends to work well if they're distributed somewhat evenly, and so on. Just some field that (reasonably) evenly divides them up.

Comment: Yes..this is a collection of all orders for me to. 
What you suggest could be a good workaround..but unfortunately I cannot filter them by date..I need the entire set :(

Comment: But at once? Can you not get one month, loop over and do whatever, get the next month and do whatever, etc? If not, would you mind updating the question to explain in more detail? There's got to be some way we can get that going.